# Is it possible to crack AES-256 ECB when provided with the ciphertext and a portion of the corresponding plaintext?

Tags: encryption, aes, block-cipher, symmetric

AES-ECB encrypts the message by breaking it into blocks and encrypting them one by one. Provided the knowledge of the ciphertext, a portion of the plaintext that corresponds to a block in the message, is it possible to crack the key without brute-forcing?